# Install Tessnet

Tags: ocr, .net-4.5, tessnet2

I'm trying for the last  to days to install tessnet2 wrapper in my project but it doesn't work.
Some times say that cant't mix .net 2 dll file with .net 4.5 project, other times throw strange exception (See photo).
Could you please help me to overcome this problem.

[image]

Comment: No; we can't help you. At least, not until you share what that "strange exception" might be. (and the other error is correct: You can't use a .NET 2.0 DLL with a .NET 4.5 project. So get a 4.0/4.5 DLL or use a 2.0/3.0/3.5 project)

Comment: They have stop developing in tessnet since 2009 and this is the last version Tessnet2 http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

Comment: You can see photo above for more info

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility issue can be solved by setting the target framework of the project: go to Project-Properties and set target framework to ".net Framework 2.0".